# Windows forms controls' sizes changes when display settings change

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I'm working on a Windows Forms project. In this project the controls' sizes are set in the designer and autosize is turned off. Yet when the display settings in Windows 7 are set to *medium (125%)* or *large (150%)*, the controls change size. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you *could* turn off this behaviour by setting your form's [**`AutoScaleMode` property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) to `AutoScaleMode.None`.

That being said, **don't** just turn auto-scaling off, because it's most likely a good thing! It makes your forms work at various resolutions and font scale settings. For example, if you design your forms but forget about users with impaired vision (e.g. people who increase the system font scaling to unusually high percentages), chances are that your form might still work, thanks to auto-scaling.

As the other answers suggest, **instead** of specifying the positions and sizes of each control in terms of fixed pixel values and then turning off auto-scaling, use automatic layout techniques:

- putting controls inside the various container elements for arranging controls (in a grid – `TableLayoutPanel`, one after the other — `FlowLayoutPanel`, etc.);
- setting the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties of each control;
- setting the `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` properties of each control.

Doing this correctly takes some practice, but makes your forms' layout much more robust.

Comment: I agree, but this is a game with a gameboard. Nothing fancy and certainly not something I'm getting paid for. So in this hobby project turning off AutoScaleMode is definitely the way to go :)

Comment: OK, sorry for the longish lecture then. (Though I still think that automatic layouting is not *that* fancy... :)

Comment: Hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi` on your UserControl or Form

Answer (score 0):

Use the Anchor and Dock properties for the controls.